# Send mail with Data Selector

Tags: rules, 9

In Drupal 9 Rules 8.x alpha 7 - I have a rule working. However, I am trying to send an email to the user of the account that is changed.

I am trying to figure out the **data selector** to make this happen. I have tried token for an email: `{{ profile.uid.entity.mail }}`
I have tried `profile.uid.entity.mail.value` as a data selector and many other things I am finding online.

I have Entity is of Bundle and Field is of type in the conditions to grab the field in the user account.

If I put in a specific email it works. Anyone figure out the data selector for this?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, it took a while but I got it to work. I am using the Profile module with the Drupal account. This rule is on Profile update.

In the Condition: you need 'Entity is of Type' - data_selector = profile, and value = profile
Then you need 'Entity has field' with data_selection = `@user.current_user_context:current_user`
and value as 'mail'

Than...You create an Action "send Mail' - in the Send to: direct input I used this `{{ profile.uid.entity.mail }}`
Added a message and tested.

It works!!!

Hope that helps someone.